# How to prove that: $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have this integral

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx$$

I know it diverges but I don't know how to prove it. We have not learned hyperbolic trig functions so I know this is related to inverse hyperbolic tangent but I am looking for another approach that does not rely on that knowledge.

Comment: Wow, what a controversial thread.  Good stuff.

Comment: On $(0,1)$, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\frac{1}{1-x^2}\geq 1+x^2+\ldots+x^{2n}$. The harmonic series is divergent, so...

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x^2-1} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1} +\frac{1}{1-x}\right)= -\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'$$
Hence, 

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx=\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]^1_{-1}=-\infty .$$

Given that, $$\color{red}{\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln\left(x\right)=-\infty,~~~~~\lim_{x\to \infty+} \ln\left(x\right)=\infty}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial fractions for sure (and logs will emerge), and consider the two improper integrals
$$
\int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{x^2-1} \ dx \ \text{ with } \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2-1} \ dx.
$$

You need BOTH to converge for your integral to converge.  Carry on...

Comment: What is the purpose of splitting it at $0$?

Comment: Honestly, it depends on how you VERY CAREFULLY define improper integrals that may be improper at several points.  Most people would define your integral if and only if it made sense at all possible split-points, not just $0$.  But with a finite number of discontinuities you can show that this doesn't matter:  examining one split-point is enough.

Comment: I don't understand. Let's say I split it and decompose into partial fractions. Both pieces will involve $\log(x+1)$ and $\log(x-1)$. The first piece will have  issues with $\log(x+1)$ due to the $-1$ bound and the second piece will have issues with $\log(x-1)$ due to the $1$ bound. Wouldn't I run into this same problem anyway if I had not split at $0$?

Comment: Right, splitting it doesn't resolve those issues.  Asymptotes will always be there.  The reason for my remarks were clear before a previous user deleted their answer.

Comment: It is easy to cook up examples where if you do not split it and treat both endpoints as limits in the same variable that stuff cancels that shouldn't and you conclude that it converges when it doesn't.

Comment: @Randall Can you give such an example to illustrate the difference?

Comment: I would, but it does not fit within the margins of this paper.  Just kidding, I have to run and teach a class, but later I will...

Comment: @user8807399 : $\int_{-1}^1 \; \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x$ should be treated as $\lim_{(a,b) \rightarrow (0^-,0^+)} \left( \int_{-1}^a \; \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{b}^1 \; \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x \right)$, which diverges.  If you take instead $a=b$, you get its [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), $0$.

Comment: @EricTowers  thank you!

Comment: @RobertZ "Here the function is even, so both integrals diverge to −∞" All these remarks are true, and irrelevant, since one must start from precise definitions, right?

Comment: @Did You are right, my comment is irrelevant. I delete it.

Comment: @user8807399: As far as I can tell, splitting is just a mnemonic device; the integral here is $$\lim_{(s,t) \to ((-1)^+, 1^-)}\int_{s}^{t} \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} \mathrm{d} x $$ (or a number of other equivalent ways to write it) Splitting the integral simply makes it difficult to make a common mistake such as writing $$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_{-1+a}^{1-a} \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} \mathrm{d} x $$

Answer (score 8):

Note that for $x\in (-1,1)$,
$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}\leq \frac{1}{(-2)(x+1)}.$$
Hence
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx\leq -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x+1}dx=-\left[\frac{\ln(x+1)}{2}\right]_{-1}^1=-\infty.$$

Comment: What does the <= part show / prove exactly? We can evaluate convergence by using some larger integral?

Comment: By comparing the two integrals we are showing that $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx=-\infty$.

Comment: I understand the intended outcome, but I am not clear on why that comparison allows us to draw that conclusion

Comment: Something that it is less or equal to some other thing that goes to $-\infty$, should go to $-\infty$ too.

Comment: Why then the use of the $-1/2$ piece on the righthand side? How do you know to use the negative and not positive?

Comment: @user8807399 See my edited answer.

Comment: Short and really straightforward, I like this! (+1)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a less orthodox answer. Consider just the interval $[0, 1)$, and divide it into intervals $[0, 1/2), [1/2, 2/3), \ldots, [1 - \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}), \ldots$, each of width $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. The value of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ at $x = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ is $\frac{n^2}{2n-1}$. Multiplying widths by function values gives a lower Riemann sum $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1-x^2} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+1) (2n-1)}$$
which diverges as the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since the integral is improper *both* at $x=-1$ *and* at $x=1$, you should split it:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{x^2-1} = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{dx}{x^2-1} + \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2-1} = \lim_{a \to -1} \int_a^0 \frac{dx}{x^2-1} + \lim_{b \to 1} \int_0^b \frac{dx}{x^2-1}.
$$
Consider the last integral, which I write as
$$
- \int_0^b \frac{dx}{1-x^2} = -\int_0^b \frac{dx}{(1-x)(1+x)}.
$$
Observe that, for $0<x<b$, $1+x<1+b<1+1=2$. Hence
$$
\int_{0}^b \frac{dx}{(1+x)(1-x)} > \frac{1}{2} \int_0^b \frac{dx}{1-x} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ -\log |1-x| \right]_0^b
$$
Now, let $b \to 1$ and deduce that
$$
\lim_{b \to 1} \int_0^b \frac{dx}{(1+x)(1-x)} = +\infty.
$$
Hence the improper integral diverges.

Comment: "First of all, since the integral is improper, you should split it" Why?

Comment: That's usually the definition of an improper integral containing more than one singular point. This is used to avoid the appearence of principal values of improper integrals.

Comment: What is a principal value and why would we want to avoid it?

Comment: Anyway, you should follows your definition of improper integral. What is it?

Comment: I'd rather learn the right way if my current understanding is lacking. I assume improper means at least one bound is infinity, or the integral evaluates to infinity at some point within the bounds. Is $\log(0)$ considered infinity?

Comment: No, I mean: if the integrand function is unbounded at two or more points inside the interval of integration, when do you declare that the improper integral converge?

Comment: I don't know, sorry I don't understand the question. I assume we just compute the integral and see if it evaluates to something not involving undefined or infinite values.

Comment: That's a bad starting point: never compute something that you are unable to define.

Comment: What do you mean? If I have the integral and then I use partial fractions, and then get the integral of each, I can change everything to a big summation involving some log functions. Is this problematic?

Comment: For instance I compute that the integral of $1/(x^2 - 1)$ is $1/2 (\log(1 - x) - \log(x + 1)) + C$

Comment: Me and @Siminore are getting at the same point:  you have to appeal to the true definition of convergence for an improper integral--whatever that means--and go from there.  For most, this definition requires you to split it and examine the discontinuities separately.  Maybe for this PARTICULAR integral it doesn't matter, but in other ones it might.

Comment: I still feel like it would help to have an example of this because right now I am not following any of this, I'm sorry

Comment: I had mentioned earlier "I assume improper means at least one bound is infinity, or the integral evaluates to infinity at some point within the bounds." Is this wrong?

Comment: You do not want to understand. What is the definition of *convergence* for an improper integral of your type?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67392/discussion-on-answer-by-siminore-how-to-prove-this-integral-diverges).

Answer (score 1):

Hin: On the interval $[0,1),$

$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}\le \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x-1}.$$

If the integral of the right side over $[0,1)$ is $-\infty,$ then the same is true of the left side.

Answer (score 0):

[The following is essentially [@Guy Fsone's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2481631/9464). It is rewritten differently.]

Observe that
$$
\frac{1}{x^2-1} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+1} +\frac{1}{1-x}\right)= -\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'
$$
Hence, 
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx=\left[-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right]^1_{-1}=\frac{1}{2}[\ln(1-x)-\ln(1+x)]\big|_{-1}^1
\tag{1}
$$
But note that, 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln\left(x\right)=-\infty \tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2) one has
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-1}\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[(-\infty-\ln 2)-\big(\ln 2-(-\infty)\big)\right]=-\infty
$$
where we use the [arithmetic operations of the extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations).